# How can I get this C# console swap cipher working?

Tags: c#, encryption, console, swap

If I wanted to make an app in C# console with VS2010 how could I make it where I input text and then it will do a 101010101010 swap?

lPyare1 = Player1

This is currently what I have:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter String Here:");
        //
        // Swap characters in the string.
        //
        string value1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string swap1 = SwapCharacters(value1, 0, 1);
        Console.WriteLine(swap1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I think he wants *us* to write `SwapCharacters`.

Comment: I can use SwapCharacters for the entire string?

Comment: what does `0, 1` do in the function?

Comment: Originally I had an array setup and it helps assign elements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is for a demonstrative application where you really mean to swap characters, and not bits (as would be required in a proper cipher), you can use this method:

```
static string SwapCharacters(string s, char c1, char c2)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
        if (s[i] == c1)
            sb[i] = c2;
        else if (s[i] == c2)
            sb[i] = c1;

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

You would need to call it using `char` parameters, not `int`:

```
string swap1 = SwapCharacters(value1, '0', '1');
```

**Edit**: To achieve what you requested in the comment:

```
static string SwapCharacters(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
    {
        if (i < s.Length - 1)
            sb.Append(s[i + 1]);
        sb.Append(s[i]);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I wanted to make it where i could swap around characters like this:

Comment: So basically swap the first 2 characters, then the 3rd and 4th, then 5th and 6th so here are more examples: lolk = olkl, water = awetr.

Answer (score 0):

The solution looks like this:

```
    string s_01 = SwapCharacters("lPyare1", 0, 1); // "Player1"
    string s_12 = SwapCharacters("Palyre2", 1, 2); // "Player2"
}
static string SwapCharacters(string source, int a, int b) { // a < b
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source);
    for(int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) {
        if(i % (b + 1) != b) continue;
        char tmp = sb[i - (b - a)];
        sb[i - (b - a)] = sb[i];
        sb[i] = tmp;
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```